# How to make Nativescript listview work

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I am doing an app with nativescript and angular 2. I am trying to use the nativescript listview component but i can't make it work, what i get when trying the app is  always " [object object] ".

This is my view code :

```
                               <grid-layout columns="*" rows="*">
                               <ListView [items]="itemsd" class="listview" #LISTV>
                                   <ListView.itemTemplate>
                                        <grid-layout columns="50, *" rows="*" class="item item-avatar">
                                            <image src="{{ '~/images/' + img }}" col="0" ></image>
                                            <stack-layout col="1">
                                                <label text="{{ artist }}" class="h2" col="1"></label>
                                                <label text="{{ title }}" class="p" col="1"></label>
                                            </stack-layout>
                                        </grid-layout>
                                   </ListView.itemTemplate>
                               </ListView>
                           </grid-layout>
```

this is my ts code here :

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fakeListItems = [{
        "img":"ANDY.jpg",
        "artist":"ANDY",
        "title":"A User"
    }]
    this.itemsd = new ObservableArray(this.fakeListItems);
}
```

I tried everything to make this listview work, but the documentation is not that good and there are many versions form different websites of telerik. Is there anyway to make this work ? and how ?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mixture of syntaxes might be to blame. Try changing your [items]="itemsd" to items="{{itemsd}}".

Here's angular 2.3 NS code from a demo-app of mine, which worked just fine:

```
  <ListView items="{{ peripherals }}" itemTap="{{ onPeripheralTap }}" separatorColor="#ffffff">
      <ListView.itemTemplate>
          <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
              <StackLayout cssClass="padded-label-stack" width="60%">
                <Label horizontalAlignment="left" text="{{ advertisement }}"/>
                <Label horizontalAlignment="left" text="{{ number1 + ' coins for €' + number2 }}"/>
              </StackLayout>
              <StackLayout cssClass="padded-label-stack" width="40%">
                <Label horizontalAlignment="right" text="{{ 'Time: ' + timestamp }}"/>
                <Label horizontalAlignment="right" text="{{ distance + 'm away' }}"/>
              </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
      </ListView.itemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

Your ts-code doesn't seem to significantly differ from mine, asides from that you don't actively make your object Observable. You initialize your array just fine.

```
observablePeripheralArray = new observableArray.ObservableArray();
peripheralArray = new Array();
peripherals = this.observablePeripheralArray;

var that = this;
var onDiscovered = function (result) {
  let extended = new ExtendedPeripheral(result);
  var obsp = new Observable(extended);
  ...
  that.observablePeripheralArray.splice(i, 0, obsp);
```

One sidenote: Consider getting Visual Studio Code with nativescript plugins, that way you can run a debugger to see what exactly your items are. Or try out JSON.stringify(this.itemsd[0]) to see if you got your structure right. And if your objects always contain the same fields, make a class for them instead.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't really work, when i change to items={{itemsd}} i start getting " [ " instead of "[object object] " . the JSON.stringify does show the items correctly. also i can iterate over the items in itemsd correctly using *ngFor but that still doesn't work as the listview. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are simply mistaking the syntax, `{{ }}` should be `[ ]`

```
<grid-layout columns="*" rows="*">
     <ListView [items]="itemsd" class="listview" #LISTV>
          <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <grid-layout columns="50, *" rows="*" class="item item-avatar">
                        <image [src]="'~/images/'+img" col="0" ></image>
                              <stack-layout col="1">
                                  <label [text]="artist" class="h2" col="1"></label>
                                  <label [text]="title" class="p" col="1"></label>
                               </stack-layout>
                 </grid-layout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
       </ListView>
</grid-layout>
```